# IAM policy variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am confused with the policy variable "${aws:username}" i.e. whether it is the IAM username from which i logged in the AWS account or 
is it the tag value that i manually entered in tags while creating instances.

Actually, i wanted to achieve that only owner of the ec2 instance should be to perform actions & othershould be denied. should the below policy works?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Owner": "${aws:username}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: its the username of the current IAM user

Comment: if you are going to do `*`, you can just say `Resource: "*"` instead of `Resource: ["*"]`

Comment: is it the current IAM user or tag value you enters??

Comment: better dont do "*", if you are targeting instances, you could do `arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The policy variable ${aws:username} is replaced with the friendly name of the current IAM user when the policy is evaluated by IAM.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-ec2-resource-tags/

Your policy should work.

Comment: could you give some example of friendly name?
I am confused, is it the name you entered in tags?

Comment: Let's say you are creating an ec2 instance . You should add a tag called `Owner` and set the value as your username of your account that you are logged in. If you don't create the tag as the policy requires, it will not let you create the instance. what's a username ? Every IAM user has a username which you enter when you create an IAM user.

Comment: the friendly name is like `arn:aws:iam::[account-ID]:user/Arun`, Arun is the friendly name here

Comment: Aran, thanks for the clarificaton. Last question, should i enter the value of tag as 'user' or 'Arun'.
Also which value should `${aws:username}` be used/display? `arn:aws:iam::[account-ID]:user/Arun` or `user` or `Arun`?

Comment: When you create policy you will use `${aws:username` as the value. When you create tag for the instance , you will use `Arun` as the value for the tag.